# How to take the first ten items of a list and cast them to dates kdb

Tags: kdb

How do I take the first 10 items from a list generated with kdb and cast them to dates?
My list is generated using 
'list1:3+20?30'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As q is evaluated left of right, 10# takes the first 10 items from list one, then `date$ casts those items to dates.

```
`date$10#list1
```

Under the covers, a kdb+ date is the number of days since the millennium i.e. 0 will be cast to 2000.01.01 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Can take items from a list with `#` and cast with `` `date$ ``:

```
`date$10#list1
```